# Image preloading function testing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would like to know if the following is an effective way of preloading images and whether there is any way of testing the preloading function? Thanks.

```js
var images = new Array();

function preload() {
 for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
  images[i] = new Image();
  images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
 }
}

// Usage:

$(window).load(function(){
 preload(
     'img/imageName.jpg',
     'img/anotherOne.jpg',
     'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
 );
});
```

Comment: @ the downvoter - please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine for preloading the images on a web page.

For testing, you can add append the images to your page and check the images you have loaded.

```
function preload() {
    var images = [];
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
          images[i] = new Image();
      images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];

              $("body").append( images[i] );
  }
}

// Usage:

$(window).load(function(){
        preload(
        'img/imageName.jpg',
        'img/anotherOne.jpg',
        'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
   );
});
```

Comment: thanks for that, however it seems to work like this `preload('1.jpg','2.jpg');` rather than `preload(['1.jpg','2.jpg']);`